# Change date from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

train_df is as below:

```
application_date
2014-12-22
2015-11-29 and so on
```

train_df.dtypes

```
 application_date     object
```

Now, code I use to change the format of date from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy is as below:
'

```
     train_df['application_date'] = train_df['application_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, 
     '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

If i again do train_df.dtypes, I am still getting application date as object

```
     application_date     object
```

If I type the below code to change application date to datetime, I get an error

```
train_df['application_date'] = train_df['application_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y- 
%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
train_df['application_date']=pd.to_datetime(train_df.application_date,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Did you post this question already? I remember seeing it earlier.

Comment: In any case, I will repeat exactly what I said then: That first `.apply(lambda)` is working exactly as expected. Your column contains strings, the lambda converts them to datetime objects, and then back to strings. You still haven't shared what the error you're getting is.

Comment: I don't think there really is much of question here, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: Found the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59801557/11301900.